# Foundation Grid Not Working. 3 Columns Layout?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have used Foundation plenty of times and everything works fine. I am trying to do three columns right above the footer and it seems to be too big: http://1stcallwebdesign.com/tracsoft/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns"> 
        <div class="four columns">
            <h2>Our Clients</h2>

        </div> 
        <div class="four columns">
            <h2>Blog</h2>

        </div> 
        <div class="four columns last">
            <h2>Expertise</h2>

        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

It should be 3 perfect columns. 4x3=12. But the columns seem to be too big and push the last one down. Any ideas?

EDIT: Same thing happening in the footer. four columns, last one being pushed. I know I could reduce the width of the columns but that will mess up the whole grid. It should just work.

Comment: AHHHH IVE FIXED IT! I just needed to make the columns: border-box

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://1stcallwebdesign.com/tracsoft/css/global.css

```
.column, .columns {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
   /* padding: 0 15px;*/ /*this will do*/
    position: relative;
}
```

OR you can do

```
.four, .row .four {
    width: 30.333%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code insted of yours:

```
.four, .row .four {
width: 30.33333%;
}
```

Reduce the width. Then your problem will fix...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know I can just reduce the width, but then that throws off the responsiveness when I resize the window.